# systemd service doesnt start

Tags: scripts, python, systemd, autostart, user-management

i have a problem with a systemd service and i cant find the problem.

I have script in the directory /home/username/test/ called battery.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
max=99999
for i in `seq 1 $max`
do
    clear
    python3 batterie.py
    sleep 5
done
```

it starts a python script named batterie.py. This script gives out a log file in the directory. I want the sh script to be autostarted, so i added batterie.service in /etc/systemd/system:

```
[Unit]
Description=Batterie Script

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/sh /home/username/test/batterie.sh
WorkingDirectory=/home/username/test
Restart=always
RestartSec=10

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then i added service to autostart with "sudo systemctl enable batterie". Now systemctl status batterie gives:

```
batterie.service - Batterie Script
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/batterie.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2023-03-16 17:58:13 CET; 2min 17s ago
   Main PID: 1117 (sh)
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 18943)
     Memory: 45.3M
     CGroup: /system.slice/batterie.service
             ├─1117 /bin/sh /home/username/test/batterie.sh
             └─1123 python3.10 batterie.py
Mär 16 18:00:21 NUC8i3BEK sh[1263]: TERM environment variable not set.
```

But there is no logfile in the directory test. But there is a log file when i start the script manually from the directory.

What did i do wrong?

Comment: I don't see evidence that the service fails to start - the `TERM environment variable not set` error is probably due to the `clear` command (which seems to have no purpose in a non-interactive context)

Comment: Ah right. Deleted it. After a fresh restart i get a log file now too. It there a way to execute the script in the name of a user and not root? The log file is owned by root now.

Comment: Probably the right way is to install it as a systemd user service (in `~/.config/systemd/user`) but I don't know much about that

Comment: i had to do a freah reinstall of new linux mint (now 21.1). Now it works with above code.